# Why would I put a reference of class2 into an object of class1?

Tags: c#, class

Ok, so I've come across this code snippet:

```
class1 a = new class1();
a.Test();

class1 b = new class2();
b.Test();
```

It had something to do with virtual and override, but my question now is:
Why type

```
class1 b = new class2();
```

when you could just type

```
class2 b = new class2();
```

because both solutions have the same output

Comment: It's a matter of abstraction. By defining your object as general as possible while stile retaining the necessary methods, you create code that can more easily be adapted.

Comment: Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

Comment: All of the answers explain polymorphism, none explain why you would want to instantiate as a base type rather than as a sub type.

Comment: @Rotem by "instatiate as base type" you mean "convert to base type" right? The primary reason to do that *is* polymorphism.

Comment: There is no point in writing it like this.  Unless class2.Test() has the *new* keyword, you don't want to write that either.

Comment: @usr No, my intent is to explain a use for `class1 b = new class2();` as the OP asked, rather than an explanation on what polymorphism is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A derived class using the "new" keyword on a method instead of "override" will behave differently depending on how it is cast.

Example:

```
class Class1
{
    public virtual void DoSomething
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class1.DoSomething");
    }
}

class Class2 : Class1
{
    public new void DoSomething
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class2.DoSomething");
    }
}

class Class3 : Class1
{
    public override void DoSomething
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class3.DoSomething");
    }
}
```

Classes 2 and 3 derive from class 1, but class 2 uses the 'new' keyword to 'hide' the virtual member of class 1, while class 3 uses the 'override' keyword to 'override' the virtual member of class 1. Here is what happens when you use these classes under the guise of their own types:

```
Class1 one = new Class1();
one.DoSomething(); // outputs "Class1.DoSomething"
Class2 two = new Class2();
two.DoSomething(); // outputs "Class2.DoSomething"
Class3 three = new Class3();
three.DoSomething(); // outputs "Class3.DoSomething"
```

They all output the right class name, as expected. But this is what happens when you use these classes under the guise of class 1:

```
Class1 one = new Class1();
one.DoSomething(); // outputs "Class1.DoSomething"
Class1 two = new Class2();
two.DoSomething(); // outputs "Class1.DoSomething"
Class1 three = new Class3();
three.DoSomething(); // outputs "Class3.DoSomething"
```

Because class 2 'hides' the method, it will output 'Class2.DoSomething' when used as its own type, but it will output 'Class1.DoSomething' when used as its base type. But because class 3 'overrides' the method, it will output 'Class3.DoSomething' whether it is used as its own type or the base type -- because it 'overrides' the base type's functionality.

(The other effect of this is that if `Class2` or `Class3` have an additional method, say `DoSomethingElse`, you won't be able to call `Class1 two = new Class2(); two.DoSomethingElse()` because `Class1` does not have that method.)

I don't know of any real-world use cases for this, but it's there, and it's the only way I can think of that using `Class1 class2 = new Class2()` would offer any real use. If `Class2` does not 'hide' any members of `Class1`, then there is no real benefit.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say, or how it has anything to do with my question. Could you elaborate? Could you also tell me about this `new` keyword and how it is used in methods?

Comment: This answer is very detailed and good, but it doesn't contain the answer to my original question, which was: what is the difference between `Class1 a = new Class3();` and `Class3 a = new Class3();`? If you could just add that small part, that would make this answer pretty much perfect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what more you could need from an answer. I believe I have explained exactly what the difference between those two statements may be. :/

Comment: I understand, from what you wrote, that `Class1 a = new Class3();` and `Class3 a = new Class3();` are the same. Here for example: "it will output 'Class3.DoSomething' whether it is used as its own type or the base type"

Comment: They're not the same entirely, just in the sense of invoking the overridden method. For example, if `Class3` defined another method not present in `Class1` at all, the statement `Class1 a = new Class3()` would result in a reference to an instance of `Class3` that is crippled of the extra functionality present in `Class3`, which would be kind of pointless.

Comment: Do you think you could edit your answer to include what you just wrote?

Comment: I have included that now.

Comment: This is probably not the right answer though, since the question explicitly states that the output is the same in both cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, not knowing where the snippet came from, none of us can answer the question at face value -- we don't know who wrote it or why, we can just explain why someone might do that or why it might have no real purpose.

Answer (score 2):

class1 is obviously a super class of class2. That way you can for instance have a list of class1 objects, all containing either class1 or class2 objects. You could simply add a and b to that list without problems.

```
class Class1 {
   public virtual void test(){
       //do something
   {
}

class Class2 : Class1 {
   public override void test(){
      // do something else
   }
}

IList<Class1> list = new List<Class1>();
Class1 a = new Class1();
Class1 b = new Class2();
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
```

Then, trying to get an item from that list, you can simply do:

```
list[0].test(); //calls test of Class1
list[1].test(); //calls test of Class2
```

That concept is called polymorphism (poly=many, morph=shape).

Comment: You can add to the list without instantiating `Class2` as a `Class1`. Casting upwards is implicit.

Comment: @Rotem I'm just going along the line of the OP's approach.

Comment: If it isn't necessary to instantiate `Class2` as a `Class1`, then why would I need it?

Comment: @Xinus you never need it. The only consequence of it is detailed in tuespetre's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say, `B1` and `B2` *both* derive from `A`. Then you might not know until runtime whether you have a `B1` or a `B2`. In that case you must statically generalize to `A` which can accommodate both subtypes. If inheritance is used correctly you don't care what the concrete runtime type is.

Example:

```
A a = GetA();

A GetA() {
 if (Random()) return new B1();
 else return new B2();
}
```

Because it can be both `B1` and `B2`, you *must* use a common base class for the variable type (`A`).

Comment: This answer has received a -1 and no feedback from the OP yet. I'm calling for feedback from both.

Comment: You are not actually answering the question, since in the example in the question, the type *is* known at compile time.

Comment: I'm kind of new to c# and I have no idea what to take out of your answer. What does `GetA()` mean? or `if (Random())`?

Comment: GetA is a function that returns a B1 or B2, but it is not known which. Trying to show why one would use a variable of type A which is the only alternative here. I'm not quite sure whether this addresses what you want to know or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of abstraction and loose coupling. If the code only depends on the type of 'class1' and not the particulars of 'class2' (which is a specific subclass of class1), then the code is more general, and you can easily switch to a different subtype of class1 without changing other code.

An example: Say you have an abstract `List` class. It has two subclasses, `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. They work more or less the same (as a list of items) but are implemented differently giving them different performance characteristics. When you write your code, you are not sure which implementation is most appropriate for your code. So you want to write your code in such a way that you don't depend on the particulars of any of the specific subclasses.

If your code only cares that the class is a `List`, then you would only need to name the concrete subclass once:

```
List x = new LinkedList();
```

Everywhere else, you can treat it as the more general `List` class. This ensures two things:

- If you decide to use `ArrayList` insted of `LinkedList`, you only need to change code in one place.
- You don't accidentally come to depend on implementation specific details of one of the concrete subclasses, e.g. by calling a method which only exist on one of them. By casting to the base class, the type checker ensures that you only can call methods shared by all subclasses. Which again means you can easier swap implementation.

For example, `List` will define some methods and properties like say `Count` and `Item`, which will then be supported by all subclasses. But the specific subclasses might also define additional methods, like say `Resize` for `ArrayList` and `IsCircular` for `LinkedList`, which only makes sense for the specific subclass.

By declaring the variable as the more general type, `List`, you ensure that you don't come to depend on some of the subclass-specific methods or properties, since the compiler will simple not let you use them.

Comment: Could you please explain it a little better? I think I'm starting to understand, I just need a little more information. Maybe add an example?

Comment: Ok, let me sum up what I think is the right answer. If you reference `class2` in a `class1` object, what you're doing is changing the object of `class1` with the override of `class2` resulting in a modified `class1`, yet without the other elements of a `class2`?

Comment: It is simpler than that. You are not modifying really modifying the object at all. At runtime, x will still be a LinkedList object in the above example. But by declaring x as the more general List type, your code becomes more flexible.

Comment: But you can only use the override methods of `LinkedList` right? Making it, technically, a modified `List`

Comment: Yes. A LinkedList is a modified (specialized) List, due to it being a subclass. By declaring the variable as the more general type List, you ensure that you only use functionality exposed by all subclasses of List.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). In short, it allows you to create multiple subclasses and treat them as they were the parent class, this has some advantages like preventing code duplication.

Comment: Lets say you have a function `f(class1 x)`, you can use the same function for class1 and class2, and don't need to create the same `f(class2 x)` as well.

Comment: @Tzach But you can pass a `class2` variable into a function that expects a `class1`, since there's an implicit conversion.  This isn't a reason to change the type of the variable.  Neither code sample uses polymorphism as it stands, and both have equal possibilities for using polymorphism in code not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another answer to address the question why someone, in his right mind, would have typed it exactly like that.

The only case where this might behave differently is if `class2` and `class1` both have a method with the same name, but do not use virtual inheritance. This can be done with the `new` keyword (or no keyword at all which will compile but trigger a well-deserved warning).

This is bad style and almost never useful. That is probably not what he intended.

It might still make sense to write it that way to document the fact that only members of `class1` are being used. He might be saying that the fact that it really is a `class2` at runtime does not play a role. This is most likely because of virtual inheritance.

**So this might be purely for documentation of intent.**

Answer (score 0):

I can explain the situation in Java, The same can be applicable in C#

From the below Code, I have created an Object (obj) referencing World class.

Since World extends both India & Belgium classes, We can make use of same Object (obj) in accessing methods of both the Classes, This kind of notation is to improve Efficiency in the code. 
It is not Mandatory either to follow the same Notation.

Hope I have answered your question, Let me know in case of any concerns :)

class World {

```
public void printName() {

    System.out.println("Name is: World");
}
```

}

class India extends World {

```
public void printName() {

    System.out.println("Name is: India");
}
```

}
class Belgium extends World {

```
public void printName() {

    System.out.println("Name is: Belgium");
}
```

}
public class Geography {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    World obj; // Declaring an Object referencing World Super Class

    obj = new India(); // Allocating M/m to India class (All V & M Ind & World Class)

    obj.printName();

    // Allocating Same Object M/m to Belgium class (All V & M BGM & World Class)

    obj = new Belgium();

    obj.printName();
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use this example of instatiating in the "Factory" pattern. That is the first usage which I can think of.

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but you have the words `this example` and there's no example in your answer. And the question does NOT ask for a usage.

Comment: @user814064 By saying 'this example' I was referring to what OP wrote in his question. 'class1 b = new class2();' is an example of object instantiation, isn't it.